# Using PHP to remove a html element from a string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I am having trouble working out how to do this, I have a string looks something like this...

```
    $text = "<p>This is some example text This is some example text This is some example text</p>
             <p><em>This is some example text This is some example text This is some example text</em></p>
             <p>This is some example text This is some example text This is some example text</p>";
```

I basically want to use something like preg_repalce and regex to remove

```
<em>This is some example text This is some example text This is some example text</em>
```

So I need to write some PHP code that will search for the opening `<em>` and closing `</em>` and delete all text in-between

hope someone can help,
Thanks.

Comment: will the string always contain only one set of <em> </em> tags?

Comment: and then there is empty `<p>` elements?

Comment: yeah the em is always there, and yes i will end up with an empty <p> but thats not an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if you are interested in a non-regex solution following would aswell:

```
<?php
    $text = "<p>This is some example text This is some example text This is some example text</p>
             <p><em>This is some example text This is some example text This is some example text</em></p>
             <p>This is some example text This is some example text This is some example text</p>";


    $emStartPos = strpos($text,"<em>");
    $emEndPos = strpos($text,"</em>");

    if ($emStartPos && $emEndPos) {
        $emEndPos += 5; //remove <em> tag aswell
        $len = $emEndPos - $emStartPos;

        $text = substr_replace($text, '', $emStartPos, $len);
    }

?>
```

This will remove all the content in between  tags.

Comment: nice and if I added on to this a bit and put something like, preg_replce("<em>", " ", $text) and preg_replce("</em>", " ", $text) then that would get rid of the <em> tags aswell?

Comment: if you dont want to preserve the <em></em> tags, instead of $emStartPos += 4 do $emEndPos += 5 ('</em>' is 5 chars long)

Comment: I cant believe, you picked this answer. There is so much code, its not neat, its not optimal..

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas I think AdriftUniform decided to use this, because its easier to read compared to regex, specially if one is not well versed with regex. I agree with you that regex does solve this in one line of code. In background, the interpreter still has to analyze the regular expression and than perform action on the text, so with that I am not sure if in this  particular case the regular expression would be more optimized? Perhaps AdriftUniform can run timing tests on each solution and use the one that is more efficient, specially if he/she is planning on processing many text blocks.

Answer (score 4):

```
$text = preg_replace('/([\s\S]*)(<em>)([\s\S]*)(</em>)([\s\S]*)/', '$1$5', $text);
```

Comment: this is along the lines of what I am looking for but I get this error Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '>'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to escape the close slash in the closing (</em>) group. (</em>) should be: (<\/em>)

Comment: gave it a go, it does nothing i am afraid

Comment: What do you mean it does nothing? I get an output of: "<p>This is some example text This is some example text This is some example text</p>
<p></p>
<p>This is some example text This is some example text This is some example text</p>"

Comment: You do realize that  (<\/em>) does not have a capital V in it right? it's a backslash '\' and then a forwardslash '/'...

Comment: i tried it m8 and it did nothing, i got out exactly what i put in - and yes i realise that thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
$text = '<p>This is some example text This is some example text This is some example text</p>
<p><em>This is the em text</em></p>
<p>This is some example text This is some example text This is some example text</p>';

preg_match("#<em>(.+?)</em>#", $text, $output);

echo $output[0]; // This will output it with em style
echo '<br /><br />';
echo $output[1]; // This will output only the text between the em
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://kopli.pri.ee/stackoverflow/7529636.php) ]**</sup>

For this example to work, I changed the `<em></em>` contents a little, otherwise all your text is the same and you cannot really understand if the script works.

However, if you want to get rid of the `<em>` and not to get the contents:

```
$text = '<p>This is some example text This is some example text This is some example text</p>
<p><em>This is the em text</em></p>
<p>This is some example text This is some example text This is some example text</p>';

echo preg_replace("/<em>(.+)<\/em>/", "", $text);
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://kopli.pri.ee/stackoverflow/7529636.php?type=replace) ]**</sup>

Comment: **Note:** This works on the assumption that there is only one `<em>` inside your string.

Comment: i see so this text strips out the <em> text but what does it leave behind, the actual <em> text i am not interested in, I want to delete it from the string and be left with the rest of the text

Comment: @AdriftUniform, my bad, I got your question a bit wrong. See the edit, it should what you asked.

Comment: Beware if you have stuff like multiline HTML. .+ doesn't match across newlines by default. It took me about an hour to finally discover [PCRE_DOTALL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.dot.php) and the /s modifier.

Comment: Very effective...was going to use php html dom class but this is far simpler and what I needed was even able to target the element by id...example: `echo preg_replace('/<em id="SomeID">(.+)<\/em>/', "", $text);`

Answer (score 1):

Use strrpos to find the first element and
then the last element. 
Use substr to get the part of string.
And then replace the substring with empty string from original string.

Comment: Why make it so complex, if you can do the hole thing with one function, one line, one match?!

Comment: @Kalle Regular Expressions are complex too. They just can be written in a very terse way. But the interpreter needs to parse and translate them. You just dont see the complexity because it happens behind the scenes.

Comment: HTML can't be parsed with regex.  What about comments or quoted strings that include the characters <em>? Or <em>…<em>…</em>…</em>.

Answer (score -4):

```
  format: $text = str_replace('<em>','',$text);
$text = str_replace('</em>','',$text);
```

Comment: OP does not want to strip all tags, but just the `<em>` tags and content.

Comment: as said above this is not what i am looking for, i only want to remove the <em> and i want to get rid of the text inbetween which strip_tags will not do