# Remove blockquotes from string?

Tags: php, regex, string

I've a php string like this:

```
I am a 
  <blockquote> <strong>string</strong> 
    <blockquote> with lot of</blockquote>
  in <a href="#">it</a>
  </blockquote>
hiya!
```

And I need to remove all blockquotes for transform it in:

```
I am a
hiya!
```

I think regex can be usefull but I can't find anything on stackoverflow nor on google and I don't know how to write by myself that.

Can someone tell me how to do it using php?

(I found this, but isn't regex and I don't know if it can remove html into the element too.
[Using PHP to remove a html element from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529636/using-php-to-remove-a-html-element-from-a-string?rq=1))

Comment: [Have you tried an HTML parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/476)

Comment: @deceze do you mean something like simple_html_dom?

Comment: [take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and read first answer :)

Comment: **TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ**  (but you get a + for not insisting on regex like most of these questions)

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 $out=preg_replace("~<blockquote(.*?)>(.*)</blockquote>~si","",' '.$str.' ');
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I don't know if other users who told me to use an HTML parser are right, even if my string is generated by Markdown, so without particolar HTML tags and mistakes...

Comment: @FezVrasta I didn't work with Markdown if Markdown can export as DOMDocument use HTML parser if not Regex is better and faster.

Comment: Keep in mind this regex won't work if you have multiple blockquote blocks which are not nested, because this uses greedy matching `.*`. You could use non-greedy matching `.*?`, but then it won't work on nested blockquotes. All in all, I don't think regex is good solution here if you want it to work in all conditions.